# Which Windows SDK is required for socket programming in VC++?

Tags: sockets, sdk

My system is having Windows7 x64 operating system. I searched for SDK in Microsft's website, which is diplaying three iso files as follows:

i.   GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso

ii.  GRMSDKIAI_EN_DVD.iso

iii. GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso

And further, there is a description which goes like this:

## ***select the ISO file to download based upon your CPU architecture. Additionally, you can use the CRC and SHA1 to validate that the ISO file download was successful.

x86 ISO File Name: GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso 
CRC#: 0xBD8F1237

## SHA1: 0xCDE254E83677C34C8FD509D6B733C32002FE3572

x64 ISO File Name: GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso 
CRC#: 0x04F59E55

## SHA1: 0x9203529F5F70D556A60C37F118A95214E6D10B5A

Itanium ISO File Name: GRMSDKIAI_EN_DVD.iso 
CRC#: 0x50EFE61D 
SHA1: 0x2093EE439193EF79A1629FD9A826CE8D4DE9A93D***